# UISearchBar tinting inconsistent on iOS7

Tags: ios, uikit, ios7, uisearchbar

So I've often used two UISearchBar's next to each other prior to iOS7 - as long as they have the same tint color they look absolutely fine, as though it's one bar with two fields.

However - I don't know if iOS7 applies a slight horizontal gradient, or if I'm just going crazy, but you can see based on this code the two bars should be identical in color:

```
if(IS_IOS_7) {
    [self.whatSearch setBarTintColor:[[EJCBrandingManager sharedManager] primaryColor]];
    [self.whereSearch setBarTintColor:[[EJCBrandingManager sharedManager] primaryColor]];
}
else {
    [self.whatSearch setTintColor:[[EJCBrandingManager sharedManager] primaryColor]];
    [self.whereSearch setTintColor:[[EJCBrandingManager sharedManager] primaryColor]];
}
```

But, it looks like this: !?

[image: Both bars]

Specifically, look at this bit (the join in the center):

[image: Zoomed crossover]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS7 does not use any solid colors. All control backgrounds in iOS7 use a special gradient. That is why you use a tint color. Even keyboard has a gradient background now. You can verify this by using DigitalColor Meter in Mac Utilities.